# Perform Fuzzy Query in JBOSS Data Grid Remote Cache

Tags: datagrid, jboss, infinispan

Currently I am trying to do Fuzzy Query with ICKLE in JBOSS Data GRID remote cache. Below is my .proto file

```
package quickstart;

/* @Indexed */
message Person {

   /* @Field(index = true, store = true, analyze = true) */
   required string name = 1;

   /* @IndexedField(index = true, store = false) */
   required int32 id = 2;

   optional string email = 3;
   optional string address = 4;

   enum PhoneType {
      MOBILE = 0;
      HOME = 1;
      WORK = 2;
   }

   /* @Indexed */
   message PhoneNumber {

      /* @Field */
      required string number = 1;

      /* @IndexedField(index = false, store = false) */
      optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
   }

   /* @Field(index = true, store = false) */
   repeated PhoneNumber phone = 5;
} 
}
```

I trying to run Below Query

```
    private void queryPersonByNamebyIckelAndFuzzyDescription() {
        String namePattern = readConsole("Enter person name pattern: ");

        QueryFactory qf = Search.getQueryFactory(remoteCache);
        Query query = qf.create("FROM quickstart.Person where name : '"+namePattern+"'~2");

        List<Person> results = query.list();
        System.out.println("Found " + results.size() + " matches:");
        for (Person p : results) {
            System.out.println(">> " + p);
        }
    }
```

But I am getting below Exception

org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=10 returned server error (status=0x85): org.infinispan.objectfilter.ParsingException: ISPN028521: Full-text queries   cannot be applied to property 'name' in type quickstart.Person unless the property is indexed and analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying it in this way would help.

```
package quickstart;

/* @Indexed 
@Analyzer(definition = "standard")*/
message Person {
/* @Field(store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES) */
required string name = 1;
```

......
.....